# PHP: Formatear Date, y luego convertir Date a String

Tags: php

*(indico con numeros y letras para que se entienda mejor la pregunta)*

Realicé un formulario en html que envía una fecha:

```
<input type="date"> //(no DateTime)
```

luego php tiene que "Formatear" este Date y "Convertirlo" a String para hacer una consulta mysql.

**El problema que tengo es que:**

> (0) La fecha que estoy recibiendo es de tipo "Date"?
>
> (1) El Date tiene formato 2017-10-09 y la quiero formatear a 2017/10/09
>
> (2) Este Date lo quiero convertir a String (para luego usarlo en la consulta mysql)

**(A)Intenté resolverlo de varias maneras, pero todas resultaron con error:**

```
$myDate = date_format($_POST['fechaDesde'],"Y/m/d"); //(1)

$fechaDesde = $myDate->format('Y/m/d');              //(2)

echo $fechaDesde; //debería tener String: 2017/10/09
```

**(B)Otro intento fallido:**

```
$myDate = $_POST['fechaDesde']; 

$fecha = Date::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $myDate);   //(1)

$fechaDesde = $fecha->format('Y/m/d');               //(2)

echo $fechaDesde; //debería tener String: 2017/10/09
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) para convertir la fecha en time y luego con [date](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) darle el formato que deses.

```
date('Y/d/m',strtotime('2017-10-09'));

date('Y/d/m',strtotime($_POST['fechaDesde']));
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Estamos ante un problema de complicación innecesaria, por lo expresado aquí:

> (1) El Date tiene formato 2017-10-09 y la quiero formatear a
> 2017/10/09
>
> (2) Este Date lo quiero convertir a String (para luego usarlo en la
> consulta mysql)

¿Acaso el valor `2017-10-09` no es ya un string? ¿Por qué hay que convertirlo a formato `2017/10/09` si la base de datos reconoce igualmente el formato `2017-10-09` como válido para compararlo con fechas o para insertarlo como fecha?

## Solución simple

```
$myDate = $_POST['fechaDesde'];
```

Y usar `$myDate` para la consulta. No hay por qué complicarse.

## Solución complicada, pero no fallida

Puedes hacerlo con `DateTime`, sólo que en tu código había dos errores en (1), primeramente referías mal la clase, **es `DateTime` no `Date`** y en segundo lugar, el formato que debes pasar ahí es el que tiene la cadena en el origen, o sea `Y-m-d`, pero estabas pasando  `Y/m/d`, y como la cadena original no tiene ese formato creaba un objeto nulo.

```
$myDate = '2017-10-09';//Ponemos el dato a mano para prueba, en tu contexto será: $_POST['fechaDesde']; 
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $myDate); //(1) aquí se pone el formato que tiene el dato original
$fechaDesde = $fecha->format('Y/m/d');                 //(2) aquí el formato final que quieres
echo $fechaDesde; //Tengo String: 2017/10/09
```

**NOTA:** Esta solución es la misma que tu intento **A**, pues `date_format` es simplemente un *alias* de `DateTime::createFromFormat`. Allí tampoco te funcionaba por lo ya explicado, porque usabas `'Y/m/d'` en las dos partes.